# Stream audio from Windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, streaming, pulse-audio

I have an Ubuntu 9.10 (alpha) computer as my primary machine, but also have a Windows machine which I keep my iTunes music on.

My high-quality speaker system is connected to my Ubuntu box. Is there any way I can stream audio to Ubuntu? (either just the music or alternatively all sound output from the Windows box)

Ideally something using PulseAudio, but I wasn't able to get that to run on Windows in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For streaming just music, [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/index.php) is a good option.

There is not a way to access iTunes shares from Linux, other than running [iTunes under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347).

You could also look at [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) which would allow your Windows iTunes to treat the Ubuntu box as a set of remote speakers.

Comment: Airfoil was something like what I was looking for. Would you happen to know of a zero-cost alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the hardware, you may be able to just connect the linear audio output on the Windows machine using an appropriate male/male 3.5 mm cable to a microphone input on the Ubuntu machine, and enable/increase volume of the mic input in the sound applet

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu, you should be able to access itunes shares with daap module that Rhythmbox can use, as well as Amarok. I've done it with my colleagues in the office before.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Airfoil, use the open-source [shairport](https://github.com/albertz/shairport/). Some guy got a hold of the RSA key that Airplay and Airport Express devices use to stream audio from iTunes.

All you have to do is compile and run it on the Ubuntu machine and it will appear as remote speakers in iTunes (bottom right in status bar). More info [here](https://github.com/albertz/shairport/).

P.S. It works great. Not much lag over wired connection or Wireless-N

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with Winamp, Shoutcast DNAS and DSP downloadable from [here](http://www.shoutcast.com/BroadcastNow). All you have to do is start the server using the `setup.bat` script, configure the two passwords and press Run server. Then open Winamp and connect to the server, and play some music. On the Linux computer open in Totem (for example) the `http://IP:PORT/listen.pls` file, where IP is the local IP address of the server computer. Good luck! `:-)`